# Console Application installation

Tags: c#, console-application

I created a console application. And Installed in my system and works fine. But my application installed automatically to the path C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft

my question is how to change the Folder name Microsoft to some other?.
Please help me

Comment: What application or extension are you using for creating the installer? What have you tried so far to fix the issue? Could you please show us the relevant part of the setup project so we could help you?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the installation yourself instead of copying some codes that you don't fully understand.

Add this to the start of the code.

```
string runningPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"/" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";
string path = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\";
string pathWithFolder = path + @"<Your folder name here>/" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";

if(!File.Exists(pathWithFolder))
    File.Copy(runningPath, pathWithFolder);
```

This code will install the application to the folder if it has not done so.

Note: Don't run this code when in debug mode.